# Why doesn't testNG assertion message get printed after each test in data-driven testing?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testng, testng-dataprovider

I am running Data-driven tests driven from a spreadsheet which are input to TestNG test Framework. In a nutshell, the framework traverses through outlook mailbox and looks for mails based on the subject. Each row in the spreadsheet is the mail subject which is an input to the test.

```
String comparisonResult = GetMail.compareMails(scenarioName);
    Assert.assertNotNull(comparisonResult,"Mail does not exist");
```

Under the hood, `comparemails` method compares the subject of the mail passed as a parameter to the method and looks for that mail in the mailbox.

I am asserting for null value when the mail does not exist and reporting with an assertion message - "Mail does not exist in the mailbox." However the assertion message is not displayed after each test failure, instead is reported a the end of all test runs i.e., after all the rows of the spreadsheet are processed.

When the assertion fails, I would **expect** it to print the assertion message on the console immediately and process the next test from the spreadsheet.

However, it prints the message at the end of the test all at once like below, assuming there were 5 failures:

```
[name=null](com.dms.testsuite.Test)  Time elapsed: 66.905 sec  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.AssertionError: Mail does not exist expected object to not be null
at org.testng.Assert.fail(Assert.java:94)
at org.testng.Assert.assertNotNull(Assert.java:404)
at com.dms.testsuite.Test.submitJob(Test.java:110)

[name=null](com.dms.testsuite.Test)  Time elapsed: 83.24 sec  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.AssertionError: Mail does not exist expected object to not be null
at org.testng.Assert.fail(Assert.java:94)
at org.testng.Assert.assertNotNull(Assert.java:404)
at com.dms.testsuite.Test.submitJob(Test.java:110)

[name=null](com.dms.testsuite.Test)  Time elapsed: 51.064 sec  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.AssertionError: Mail does not exist expected object to not be null
at org.testng.Assert.fail(Assert.java:94)
at org.testng.Assert.assertNotNull(Assert.java:404)
at com.dms.testsuite.Test.submitJob(Test.java:110)

[name=null](com.dms.testsuite.Test)  Time elapsed: 51.735 sec  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.AssertionError: Mail does not exist expected object to not be null
at org.testng.Assert.fail(Assert.java:94)
at org.testng.Assert.assertNotNull(Assert.java:404)
at com.dms.testsuite.Test.submitJob(Test.java:110)

[name=null](com.dms.testsuite.Test)  Time elapsed: 67.177 sec  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.AssertionError: Mail does not exist expected object to not be null
at org.testng.Assert.fail(Assert.java:94)
at org.testng.Assert.assertNotNull(Assert.java:404)
at com.dms.testsuite.Test.submitJob(Test.java:110)
```

and the results are reported as follows:

```
Failed tests: 
com.dms.testsuite.Test.[name=null](com.dms.testsuite.Test)
  Run 1: Test.submitJob:110 Mail does not exist expected object to not be null
  Run 2: PASS
  Run 3: Test.submitJob:110 Mail does not exist expected object to not be null
  Run 4: PASS
  Run 5: Test.submitJob:110 Mail does not exist expected object to not be null
  Run 6: PASS
  Run 7: Test.submitJob:110 Mail does not exist expected object to not be null
  Run 8: Test.submitJob:110 Mail does not exist expected object to not be null
```

**Edit:** Adding the class code:

```
public class SubmitJobTest extends BaseClass implements ITest {

  private String name;

  @BeforeSuite
  public void generateXML() {
    try {
      XMLGenerator.mapper();
    } catch (ValidityException e) {      
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ParsingException e) {      
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {      
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  @Test(dataProvider = "files", dataProviderClass = FolderReader.class)
  public void submitJob(final String name) throws Exception {
    final SubmitJobEndpoint submitJobObj = new SubmitJobEndpoint();
    String submitJobId = null;
    try {
      final BaseClass obj = new BaseClass();
      obj.getPropValues();
      submitJobId = submitJobObj.submitJob(name.toString(), BaseClass.queue,
      BaseClass.config, BaseClass.type);
  System.out.println("Job Id : " + submitJobId);
  Assert.assertNotNull(submitJobId, "Job creation failed");
} catch (final InvalidKeyException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
} catch (final NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
} catch (final ClientProtocolException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
} catch (final URISyntaxException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
} catch (final IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}

final JobDetailEndpoint JobDetailObj = new JobDetailEndpoint();

String status = null;

while (true) {
  Thread.sleep(15000);
  status = JobDetailObj.GetJob(submitJobId);
  if (status.equalsIgnoreCase("FINISHED")
      || status.equalsIgnoreCase("FAILED")
      || status.equalsIgnoreCase("SPOOLED")) {
    break;
  }
  System.out.println("Output :: " + status);
}

if (status.equalsIgnoreCase("SPOOLED")) {
  Assert.assertEquals(status.toUpperCase(), "SPOOLED",
      "Email creation failed");
} else {
  Assert.assertEquals(status.toUpperCase(), "FINISHED",
      "Email creation failed");

  Map<String, List<String>> Scenario = ExcelReader.excelReader();
  String scenarioName = FilenameUtils.removeExtension(name);
  Assert.assertNotNull(Scenario.get(scenarioName),
      "Test is not enabled in xls");

  if (Scenario.get(scenarioName).get(1).equalsIgnoreCase("email")) {
    Double comparisonResult = GetMail.compareMails(scenarioName);
    Assert.assertNotNull(comparisonResult,
        "GeneratedMail or BaselineMail does not exist | ");
    Assert.assertTrue((comparisonResult) == 100,
        "Generated mail content is not the same | ");
  }
}
```

}

**Edit:** Data provider code

```
public class FolderReader {

  @DataProvider(name = "files")
  public static Object[][] GetFileNames() {
final File folder = new File("//Testing_XML_source");
final File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
final List<Object[]> list = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
for (final File file : listOfFiles) {
  if (file.getName().toString().endsWith(".xml")) {
    // System.out.println("File : " + file.getName().toString());
    list.add(new Object[] {file.getName().toString()});
  }
}
return list.toArray(new Object[list.size()][]);
  }
}
```

**Edit:** Baseclass code

```
public class BaseClass {
  public static String queue;
  public static String config;
  public static String type;
  InputStream inputStream;

  public void getPropValues() throws IOException {

try {
  final Properties prop = new Properties();
  final String propFileName = "config.properties";

  inputStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(propFileName);

  if (inputStream != null) {
    prop.load(inputStream);
  } else {
    throw new FileNotFoundException(
        "property file '" + propFileName + "' not found in the classpath");
  }

  // get the property value and print it out
  BaseClass.queue = prop.getProperty("queue");
  BaseClass.config = prop.getProperty("config");
  BaseClass.type = prop.getProperty("type");

} catch (final Exception e) {
  System.out.println("Exception: " + e);
} finally {
  inputStream.close();
}
  }

}
```

Comment: Could you share the code of the class?

Comment: @juherr - have added the class code now.

Comment: Could you share the code of the data provider? And why not, the BaseClass too.

Comment: @juherr - have added dataprovider and baseclass code but just curious to know how is baseclass code useful for your analysis?

Comment: `BaseClass` has often configuration methods and can modify the behavior.

Comment: @juherr - any update on this pls?